# Alternative to single underscore for unused variables

Tags: python, naming-conventions, gettext

In Python it is good practice to use a single underscore for intentionally unused variables:

```
first_word, _ = 'only only is important'.split(' ', 1)
```

On the other hand, [`gettext`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/gettext.html) uses the underscore as a short alias for its translation function, leading to clashes if the underscore is used for a variable before:

```
print(_('gettext will try to translate this string.'))
```

**Question:** What is the convention for the name of throwaway variables if `gettext` is used in the same namespace?